# Is there a penalty for misplaying?

Tags: uno

This afternoon my wife tried to play a green 8 on top of a red 2 in **Uno**.

Obviously a mistake on her part and I could find nothing in the rules to suggest that there was a penalty so we allowed her to withdraw the green 8 and play another card.

The rules do state that a **Wild Draw 4** play can be challenged, but no other misplays are called out that I saw.

Is anyone aware of this situation being covered, perhaps in a previous ruleset, or maybe I'm just overlooking it (It's been known to happen!)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The penalty for misplaying a card, is that now your opponents know you have that card in your hand. Besides that though, the [official rules](http://unotips.org/pdf/official_rules.pdf) (2003) state the penalty (among other listed penalties):

> If a player plays a wrong card and it is noticed by any other player, he/she must take the card back and take two extra cards from the DRAW pile. Play continues with the next player in turn.

It appears as if the penalty section was removed from the [2008 printing](http://service.mattel.com/instruction_sheets/UNO%20Basic%20IS.pdf).

Comment: Since this game is a fun family game, and is so easy, we have penalties for: asking if it is your turn to play, playing a wrong card, and also taking to much time just staring at the board (prob you don't know who turn it is)...

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Something in the back of my mind was thinking that there was an explicit penalty.  Thanks

Comment: @PatLudwig: We also have similar penalties, we always draw 2 for a penalty with all the different friends I've played against. In fact we introduce new rules (silent 7's - speak while a 7 is face up, slap down 9's - last person to slap their hand on top of the 9, saying either 'sorry' or a person's name. We tend to introduce them slowly as you get into the game and add anything extra we can think off!)

Comment: I love that the rules say `and it is noticed by any other player` - half the fun of Uno is cheating :)