# What rules changes have there been in Uno?

Tags: history, uno

A [previous question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/8436/40) revealed that there has been at least one (albeit minor) rules change for Uno recently.

This makes me curious to know if there have been any other changes to the rules over the years.

**How does today's Uno differ from the Uno of my youth?**  I'm only referring to standard Uno, not any themed version.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A definitive answer would require someone who has a collection of all the printing of UNO since the beginning in 1971 to present day. The only one likely to have such an museum quality collection is the estate of the inventor of the game, [Merle Robbins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merle_Robbins), an Ohio barber. He spent $8,000 to have 5,000 copies made. He sold the rights to the game to International Games Inc., which was bought by Mattel in 1992, who now owns the rights to the game.

Here is my best attempt at answering. I am going to assume that the 1983 International Games, Inc. edition is the same as original 1971 printing. The differences in the many spin off versions of UNO ([30th Anniversary Edition], [Batman UNO](http://service.mattel.com/instruction_sheets/M1006.pdf), [Hanna Montana UNO](http://service.mattel.com/instruction_sheets/K6505-0920.pdf), [Spongebob UNO](http://service.mattel.com/instruction_sheets/N5836-0920.pdf), [Dora UNO](http://service.mattel.com/instruction_sheets/b5033-3L.pdf), [Mickey Mouse Clubhouse UNO](http://service.mattel.com/instruction_sheets/N5831-0920.pdf), [Cars 2 UNO](http://service.mattel.com/instruction_sheets/T8230%20Uno%20Cars2.pdf), [Harry Potter UNO](http://service.mattel.com/instruction_sheets/T8231-0920.pdf), etc.) are thankfully not included. I will mention that in general, the spin-offs have nearly identical rules, but instead of including blank cards like the most recent printings, these blank cards are replaced with special cards that have some unique effect. I would guess that the reason for the +4 blank cards from the original printing is related to card manufactures changing from 54 cards=9x6, to 56 cards=8x7 sheets.

The complete rules for the 1983 version are listed, with only differences for other versions listed. The 4 previous versions (1971-1981) are assumed to exist, because they are listed as additional copyright dates within the 1983 rule book. There are gigantic gaps in the editions, because I have been unable to find scans of the intervening years. To summarize the differences though, most versions have nearly identical rules. The earliest version only uses the (0-9) face cards for **First Dealer** selection, requires a challenged player to only reveal the color of the cards in their hand, if "caught" in a challenge they keep their **Wild Draw4** card, and specifies a penalty for suggesting plays to your opponents. The **2001** editions (including 30th Anniversary) have a printing error in my mind, because no other versions I have seen make you **Draw 4** cards when failing to call "UNO." I don't think the game rules have changed much in 40 years.

- 1971 First Edition
- 1973
- 1979
- 1981
- [1983 International Games, Inc.](http://www.gamearchives.org/rules/InternationalGames_Uno_qu.pdf)

> **Components** - 108 cards, 4x Wild, 4x Wild Draw4, 4 colors each;19x (0-9);2x Draw2;2x Skip;2x Reverse
>
> **Object** - Score 500 points by emptying your hand before your opponents
>
> **First Dealer** - Non-number cards are not used. Players who draw a non-number replace it in the deck and draw another. (This differs from all subsequent versions I have found. In newer editions, non-number cards are not replaced in the deck allowing that player to redraw a card. There are other differences from later editions that will be noted, but this difference will only be noted here). Shuffle and deal 7 cards to each player, place the top card in the discard, and the remaining cards become the drawpile. The person to the left of the deal starts. With the exception of the **Wild Draw4** (replace in deck redraw) and the **Wild** (starting player decides color), Special Word cards affect the stating player in the normal manner.
>
> **Summary of Play** - Play a matching number, color, word, or wild to the top card of the discard. If a player cannot play, they must draw a card (which can be played immediately if it matches). Play passes to the next player. If the drawpile is depleted, resuffle all cards except the top card of the discard to form a new drawpile, and continue play.
>
> **Reneging** - You may choose to draw a card, even if you have a playable card in hand. If you do so though, only the drawn card can be played. You can play a drawn **Wild Draw4** card, but might be subject to getting "caught" if you have a playable color card in your hand.
>
> **Special Word Cards** - **Wild** can always be played. Choose a new color. **Wild Draw4** can only be played if you do not have a matching color (matching number/word is ok) without being subject to "caught" rules. Choose a color, the next player draws 4, play continues with the player after the next. **Draw2** the next player draws 2 cards, play continues with the player after them. **Skip** the next player is skipped, play continues with the player after them. **Reverse** the direction of play is reversed until the end of the hand, or the next Reverse card.
>
> **Going Out** - As a player plays his next to last card, they must say "UNO" before the card hits the discard. If they fail to do so before the next player has draws/plays a card and are "caught", they immediately draw 2 cards. After the next player plays/draws, they are safe. When a player plays their last card, the hand is over. Points are scored, all cards are collected, the deck is shuffled, and a new hand begins with the player to the left of the dealer. If the last card played is a Draw2 or Wild Draw4, those cards are added to the next players hand before points are scored for the hand.
>
> **Scoring** - When a player goes out, all other players card values are added that players total. First player to 500 points wins. **Wild**, **Wild Draw4**: 50 pts, **Draw2**, **Skip**, **Reverse**: 20 pts, All number cards (0-9): **Face Value**. **Variation**: Running totals for each player can be kept instead. When one player's total reaches 500 (or some other value), the game is over and the player with the **least** points wins.
>
> **Penalties** - **Fail to call UNO on next to last card** draw 2 cards, **Make a suggestion to another player on what card to play** draw 4 cards, **Play a Wild Draw4 card with/without another legal color** draw 4 cards. The next player is the only one who can challenge. If they do, you must reveal the color of the cards in your hand to verify if the play was legal. If it was, the challenger draws an additional 2 cards (6 total), if instead you are "caught", you draw 4 cards. (**Challenge** In this version, **only the color** of the cards in your hand need to be revealed. Subsequent versions do not clarify what "reveal your hand" means. Another peculiarity of note here, is that in this version the **Wild Draw4** card is returned to the "caught" player's hand, and the a correct color card is played. All subsequent versions leave the **Wild Draw4** in the discard pile. This does have an unusual effect on the gameplay. With this rule, it is not possible to sacrifice getting "caught", with the only goal of changing the current color.)

**Note:** Houserules you might have played with. **Piling On/Progressive UNO** - It allows the normal recipient of a **Special Word** card to pile on the result to the next player. (i.e. If someone plays a **Draw2** card on you, you can play a **Draw2** card, making the next player draw a total of 4 cards.). **Draw until you have a playable card** - Instead of drawing a single card when you cannot make a legal play, you continue to draw until you have a playable card.

- 1984-1992 International Games, Inc.
- 1992-2001 Mattel, Inc.
- [2001](http://service.mattel.com/instruction_sheets/42001pr.pdf) **First Dealer** is highest point value card. **Going Out** failing to call "UNO" and getting "caught" **draws 4 cards**, no penalty for opponent play suggestions. **4x Blank Cards** for adding special rules, or just replacement cards.
- 2002
- [2003](http://unotips.org/pdf/official_rules.pdf) **First Dealer** highest number goes first (word cards are 0). **Penalties** New penalty for making incorrect plays, the offending player takes the card back and draws 2 cards.
- 2004-2006
- [2007 Deluxe](http://service.mattel.com/instruction_sheets/M2062-0920.pdf) **First Dealer** highest number goes first (word cards are 0). **Penalties** no penalty for opponent play suggestions.
- [2008](http://service.mattel.com/instruction_sheets/UNO%20Basic%20IS.pdf) **First Dealer** highest number goes first (word cards are 0). **Penalties** no penalty for opponent play suggestions. First mention of **Houserule** Progressive UNO.
- 2009-present

Comment: Has there been any further changes since 2012?

Answer (score 0):

There are many changes today, but not because of the company. Most changes are known as Mandela Effects. These would include that stacking is not allowed (where one player lays a draw 2 and instead of the next player drawing that amount, they can lay a draw 2 causing the next player to draw 4.) However, the rule than changed again allowing stacking on draw 2 but not draw 4.

The other change (Mandela effect) was the fact if you drew a card that cannot be played, no card is lay down, and it goes to the next person. (Even if that card can play, you cannot lay it down) VS the idea you keep drawing until a playable card can be laid down.

Hand trading, shuffling between players, and playing out of turn is now allowed as it was not before.

The game is not won by last card being lay down but by a score system no one has ever heard of. First person to 500 wins!

A total of UNO Mandela Effects (changes) are listed at this link: http://mandelaeffectmainweb.website2.me/list8

Comment: Nice info! Would love to see some confirmation of this via scans of rules showing the changes over time, though.  I don't see a lot much proof at the link.

Comment: I don't see any of these rules mentioned in the quotes or source provided by the existing answer. They all appear to be house rules, or ignorance of what the rules do say. That would mean they aren't changes to the rules "only referring to standard Uno" and this is not an answer to the question as asked.