# If the starting card is a Wild, does the starting player still play after picking a color?

Tags: uno

I've noticed that while playing Uno with friends we had a situation that came up that I am not 100% sure with, again we are playing **official** rules.

If the first card off the top of the deck is a wild card, I understand the person to the left of the dealer chooses a colour but does he/she also place/draw a card in the same turn or is it up to the player next to him/her?

Comment: The normal rule is that the player-to-dealers-left plays the first card.  If the wild card exception rule doesn't say that the player-to-dealers-left **doesn't** play a card, then I assume that he would.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.unorules.com/

> If the first card turned up from the Draw Pile (to form the Discard
>   Pile) is an Action card, the Action from that card applies and must be
>   carried out. The exceptions are if the Wild or Wild Draw Four cards
>   are turned up, in which case – Return them to the Draw Pile, shuffle
>   them, and turn over a new card.

Answer (score 0):

From the [latest rules](http://service.mattel.com/us/productDetail.aspx?prodno=41940&siteid=27) (emphasis mine):

> **Wild Card -** ... If this card is turned up at the beginning of play, the person to the left of the dealer chooses the color to begin play *and plays the first card*.

The rule has been in place for a while, [What rules changes have there been in Uno?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/8442/what-rules-changes-have-there-been-in-uno)

Comment: There are two sets of rules on that page.  One says "If a Wild card is turned up at the beginning of play, the person to the left of the dealer chooses the color that continues play. [...] If [Wild Draw 4] turned up at the beginning of play, return this card to the deck and pick another card."  The other says "If the top card is a Wild or Wild Draw 4, return it to the deck and pick another card."

Comment: There is still some confusion. The rules (papercopy) that you get with each deck says that if a wild card is turned up first at the beginning the player to the left of the dealer chooses the colour that continues play, nothing about whether this same player plays a card or the player to his/her left plays/draws a card.

Comment: We had player to the right of the starting color chooses the color of an initial wild. If it weren't for the fact that most of us didn't have big enough hands yet to shuffle I'm pretty sure that would have been dealer. Since the rulebook was missing in action before any of us could read either, it could just as well have been a local rule.