# UNO do I need to call it again?

Tags: uno

Ok - help me solve a family argument! I called UNO on my last card, but the player immediately before me on the next round played a miss a turn card. Do I need to call uno again or because I missed a turn am I covered?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean. Are you saying you went from 1 card in your hand to 2 cards and back down to 1 card or something else?

Comment: Related (or maybe dupe actually): https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/39590/do-i-need-to-call-uno-after-swapping-hands?rq=1

Answer (score 5):

The official rules state:

> When you play your next-to-last card, you must yell “UNO” (meaning “one”) to indicate that you have only one card left. If you don’t yell “UNO” and you are caught before the next player begins their turn, you must draw two cards.

It says nothing about calling UNO when your turn comes up or if you somehow end up with 1 card in your hand via other means (swapping hands, etc.).

Comment: I don't think this applies in this case because I think the op is just asking if they have to call uno again when they have a single card in their hand and their turn was also skipped. So it is not about ending with 1 card in hand but starting and ending with 1 card in hand while taking no action.

Comment: @joe-w It doesn't seem like there's a situation where a skipped player could also play a card to trigger the requirement for calling out 'Uno'.

Comment: @KMR That is why I asked the op for clarification as I don't see how a player can go change cards in hand when they are skipped turn wise.